# Rails - Multiple models on one from, no parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

How would I use one form to submit multiple parent models in one action?

I'm familiar with the rails concept of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  As far as I know though, you need a parent model you can submit child models to.

The question I have though, is what about multiple models with no parent in a single form.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "Can it be done?" questions are meaningless. Almost anything can be done with enough effort. And yes this can be done by either creating the form inputs manually and iterating through the params in the controller or more elegantly by using a virtual model that wraps the records and serves a stand in for the parent record. Mass create/updates are inherently complex though so its a pretty substantial job.

Comment: Thank you Max, I guess I should have worded that better.  In your comment you make an interesting recommendation, if you create an answer demonstrating your concept, I'll accept it as the answer.